# Spring Framework - Design pattern to create a rules engine for game

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection, game-engine

I am looking for a design pattern or a way to use spring framework that will allow me to have a set of rules or instructions based on game difficulty level. I would have them in a spring configuration and use profiles but the problem is that they need to be defined at runtime. Any help is appreciated.

The problem becomes that I just keep passing this context object below:

```
public class Game {

     private MapMaker mapmaker;

     @Autowired
     public(MapMaker mapmaker){
         this.mapmaker = mapmaker;
     }

     public void createGame(DifficulyLevel level){
          Boss myBoss = getBoss(difficultyLevel);   
          BossWeapon = getBossWeapon(difficultyLevel);
          MapInstructions mapInstructions = getMapConstructionInstructions(diffcultyLevel); 
          mapmaker.makemap(mapInstructions);      
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easyrules framework is quite simple and effective, you can integrate with spring very easily. Since it's when/then based framework, I think it will help you on your purpose.

```
@Rule(name = "dummy rule")
public class DummyRule {

    @Condition
    public boolean when() {
        return true;
    }

    @Action
    public void then(){
        System.out.println("Hey, I'm managed by Spring");
    }
}
```

Ref : http://www.easyrules.org/tutorials/spring-tutorial.html

Comment: I like the idea but how what would be a good way of storing the configs?
Like the problem is that if you are loading the configs in some fashion like 
Map<difficultyLevel,Boss>
Map<difficultLevel,Weapon>
Map<DifficultyLevel,Instructions>

This still becomes kind of a smell. Not sure how to deal with loading the configs. Like say the maps were loaded through @Configuration or something. Basically just looking for a strategey/clean way to load the configs now as I like this solution.

Comment: Since difficulty level is depended upon user you can create different rules class for different difficulty level and use them in the main class. Just an idea, advising you to think carefully. You will come up with a solution.